# subtract nth item from list from nth item in different list in Python

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I want to modify this code:

```
def differenceinX(list1,list2):
    answer=[n1 - n2 for (n1, n2) in zip(list1, list2)]
    return answer
```

to something like:

```
def differenceinX[x](list1[x],list2[x]):
    answer=[n1 - n2 for (n1, n2) in zip(list1[x], list2[x])]
    return answer
```

I have 2 lists `(23,24,26), (24,24,25)` and I want to be able to subtract the 1st item in the first list from the 1st item in the second list. I get error message 'invalid syntax'

Comment: "subtract the 1st item in the first list from the 1st item in the second list" So why the `for` loop? `return list2[0] - list1[0]`

Comment: Show an example of the output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you are looking for,

```
def differenceinX(list1,list2, index):
  answer = list1[index] - list2[index]
  return answer
```

Comment: You don't need to assign to the variable answer, just return it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the output as a single number for one list item, then use this:

```
def differenceinX(list1, list2, x):
    return list1[x] - list2[x]
```